# D3 scaleLinear() returns rgb value although the range is in hex values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

`d3.scaleLinear()` returns an rgb string value although the range is mapped with hex values. Is there something incorrect in my usage?

```
const value = 0;
col = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 16000]).range(["#ffdc00","#ffa900"]);
console.log(col(value));
//returns rgb(255, 220, 0)
```

Comment: This is the expected behavior, you are using it correctly, the scale will not return hex values unless you use a custom interpolator. Though you could use [d3.color](https://github.com/d3/d3-color#color_formatHex) to create a hex value out of the value returned by the scale.

Answer (score 4):

`d3-scale` relies on `d3-interpolate`, which uses `d3.interpolateRgb` by default whenever colors are detected ([source](https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate#interpolate)):

> If b is a color or a string coercible to a color, use interpolateRgb.

As stated in the documentation for [`d3.interpolateRgb`](https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate#interpolateRgb):

> The return value of the interpolator is an RGB string.

The behaviour is therefore normal, and the provided code sample is perfectly fine.

RGB strings are equivalent to their hexadecimal representation, so they may be used directly.

If the use case requires to have a hexadecimal string, the function [`color.formatHex`](https://github.com/d3/d3-color#color_formatHex) from `d3-color` can be used, as illustrated in the snippet below:

```js
const value = 0;
col = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 16000]).range(["#ffdc00","#ffa900"]);

let rgbValue = col(value)

console.log('rgb string:', rgbValue);

console.log('hex string:', d3.color(rgbValue).formatHex());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.15.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```